# Why am I getting this error?pipe is not a function

Tags: angular, subscribe, angular-pipe

This returns the dropdown options available to be displayed. I'm assuming the problem is with the .pipe but I can't seem to correct it.

````
        return this.lasService.getLasDropDownOptions(true)
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
          .subscribe((lasOptions) => {
            return resolve(lasOptions.map((option) => {
              return option || [];
            }));
          });
      }
   

 getLasDropDownOptions(refresh) {
    return this.getLasData(refresh)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe((response) => {
        return response.map((las) => {
          las.displayValue = las.name + ' - ' + las.expression;
          if (!las.status) {
            las.disabled = true;
            las.category = 'Calculating';
          } else {
            las.category = las.longterm ? 'Online Range' : 'Short Term';
          }
          return las;
        });
      });
  } ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your service method returns a `Subscription`, not an observable. You should use the `map` operator in your service method and not `.subscribe` to the observable there.

```
getLasDropDownOptions(refresh) {
  return this.getLasData(refresh).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
    map((response: any[]) => {
      return response.map((las) => {
        las.displayValue = las.name + " - " + las.expression;
        if (!las.status) {
          las.disabled = true;
          las.category = "Calculating";
        } else {
          las.category = las.longterm ? "Online Range" : "Short Term";
        }
        return las;
      });
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Both the error you encountered at first, with .pipe does not exist, and also the one you mentioned in your comment are due to the fact that you don't fully embrace typescript. You could have caught this one at compile time with proper typing. To solve this new one, just instruct typescript that the response you are expecting is an array. Please check the updated answer.